# Shutting down hard-disks from their on/off button or directly turning on/off the power point?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, power-management

I have 4 `hard-disks` connected to a power point I can turn off with a button, to avoid troubles I always turn off the disks with their turn `on/off` button, but I don't know if I can simply use power point button without compromise their health.

So, can I turn on/off all my `hard-disks` directly from the power point or should I always use their on/off button?

Obiouvsly with ejected hard-disks from the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have one that doesn't have an on/off switch on it, so I have no choice. I've been switching it off from the wall for over a year with no issues.

I don't think it matters.

In the old old old days... I'm talking 1980's, it used to matter.  You had to "park" the drive heads before removing power.  This meant they got moved to a safe position.  But nowadays the drives automatically park themselves with no fear of data loss.